# SSL certificate migration from one server to another

Tags: ssl, migration, certificate

What's necessary to migrate valid SSL certificate from one server and service provider to another?

Answer (score 7):

In some cases it may be simply a matter of copying the keys to and changing apache configuration on the new server.

For example:
http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-ssl-export.htm

Some certificate authorities may tie an SSL certificate to a specific server.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you export SSL certificates from the server that they are currently installed on, move SSL certificates to the new server, and then import SSL certificates on the new server. But this only really only applies if you are sticking with the same certificate authority ("provider")... which it sounds by your question that you are not.

Keep in mind that even if you stick with the same provider, many require that you purchase a "server license" for each server that you install an SSL certificate to, even if it uses the same private key. And speaking of private keys, it is slightly less secure to copy the SSL certificate and use the same private key on a different server. If an attacker breaks into one server and gets the private key, he will be able to listen in on the connections that other servers are making.

So my advice to you since you want to switch providers is just purchase a new one all together with the new provider once you move to the new server... But maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 2):

First determine if the device installed with the certs are storing the private key in hardware/software. In most today's servers, they are in software *.key files (e.g. web server SSL). 
To be found near the key files are the certificate and perhaps even CSR. Moving these files to another server is generally allowed (Considering the destination server will have the same hostname) and hence keeping the same CA. Most CAs have no concern to customers who does that.

But if you are just looking to switch the service provider from one to another, simply ask current CA to 'revoke' the cert. Then start with the new Cert buying process with the new CA.